# how do i incorporate a set into this Python code so it can work the same way as it does already

Tags: python, list, function, set

This code inputs a list of numbers and outputs only the numbers of the list that have positive and a negative sign. So for example it inputs the list (2,3,4, -2,-3) and the output is (2,3,-2,-3).

This function does work, but I am looking for how to make this function output a `set` such that there are no duplicates.

```
def pos_neg(a):
  return [i for i in a if -i in a]
```

Comment: You can literally write `set()` around that list.

Comment: You don't even need the list, you can just do ``set(i for i...)``, which saves an unneeded list allocation and iteration. Though it's actually probably much more efficient to turn `a` into a set first via ``set(a)`` so that your ``in`` is **O(1)** rather than **O(n)**. And if you really want to get fancy, you can maintain input order by then sorting the de-duped list by index location in the input list.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the two comments, you can just replace the brackets with braces:

```
def pos_neg(a):
    return {i for i in a if -i in a}
```

Or, to make it faster for long lists:

```
def pos_neg(a):
    return {-i for i in a}.intersection(a)
```

Or, if you want to return a list again:

```
def pos_neg(a):
    return list({-i for i in a}.intersection(a))
```

The returned list will not be ordered, however. If you want to return an ordered list (by size):

```
def pos_neg(a):
    return sorted({-i for i in a}.intersection(a))
```

If you want to return a list that preserves the original order, do this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def pos_neg(a):
    s = set(a)
    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(i for i in a if -i in s))
```

Or, if you don't want to use OrderedDict:

```
def pos_neg(a):
    s = set(a)
    t = set()
    b = []
    for i in a:
        if -i in s and i not in t:
            t.add(i)
            b.append(i)
    return b
```

Or, if you want to use list comprehension:

```
def pos_neg(a):
    s = set(a)
    t = set()
    return [i for i in a if -i in s and not (i in t or t.add(i))]
```

Comment: Thank  you.. is there any way i can put a set into the function..but make the output of the function still be a list

Comment: I have added some solutions for returning a list to the answer.